# Silverlight unit testing integration in VS 2010?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, resharper

I'm currently using the Silverlight Unit Test Framework, but I'd prefer to run tests directly in VS2010.  I'm curious to know what approaches and tools everyone else uses.

I'm using Silverlight 4 with Prism and the MVVM pattern, and I'm specifically interested in integrated Silverlight unit test support in VS 2010 that I can use with my ViewModel unit tests.  I'm using dependency injection with Unity, and I am writing unit tests by mocking the calls in my WCF layer using Moq for Silverlight.  I am not even looking at integration tests at the moment, but even in a simple unit test which tests a single ViewModel command, the service request to my mocked service layer can take around 50 milliseconds.  Therefore support for asynchronous tests is important to me.

The issue I'm raising here is not related to View testing, which I have handled with some success in the past using System.Windows.Automation.Peers, and - although I have not used it yet - could possibly now handle more easily with the support in VS 2010 Feature Pack 2 (which appears to be targeted at automation / playback of UI tests from what I gather).

I should mention that my findings from the products I've looked at and used so far are as follows:

- Silverlight Unit Test Framework - I currently use this, and it's great as far as it goes, but its limitations are (a) it is not integrated with Visual Studio; and (b) if you don't want to run all tests, you are limited to the crude tag expression filter.
- StatLight - very nice.  I currently use this, and have used it since v0.9 when targeting Silverlight 3 on a previous project.  Being a command-line tool, it can be integrated with a continuous integration server - which certainly handles another required scenario.  But it is of no use directly in terms of Visual Studio integration during the development process.
- Unit Test Result Viewer for Silverlight (Visual Studio extension on the Visual Studio gallery) - looks promising, but its limitations are (a) currently fails to find projects which are located in solution folders, rather than under the solution root; and (b) runs *all* tests in a given assembly (via StatLight), with no apparent ability to run a specific test, or a selection of tests.
- Einar Ingebrigtsen's Silverlight Unit Test Runner for ReSharper, which later became Odin - ahead of the game (it first appeared in 2008), but the limitation is that it appears that this project is no longer maintained (most recent update is Apr 2009).
- AgUnit ReSharper plugin ( http://agunit.codeplex.com/ ) - looks excellent initially. After downloading the source code for it and building the latest (bug-fixed) version to work against ReSharper 5.1, I was very encouraged.  But unfortunately it does not handle asynchronous tests.  This is a design limitation with the threading, so it does not matter whether you try to use the asynchronous support that is built into Silverlight Unit Test Framework (Microsoft.Silverliht.Testing.SilverlightTest base class), or whether you're using AutoResetEvent or anything else.  This has been noted by the coordinator on the project's discussion forum on CodePlex.  This is a massive limitation.
- TestDriven.NET 3.0 - appears to have support for Silverlight 4.0 tests at first glance, but the limitation (I suspect) is Silverlight 4 "assembly portability" (i.e. the 5 dependent assemblies that are portable between SL4 and .NET 4).  Certainly, when I tried using it with a simple POC, it crashed my instance of VS 2010.

Perhaps I've missed something here - I wonder if anyone in the community has any better ideas for Silverlight unit testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Silverlight Unit test framework, AgUnit, and RX with a mock IScheduler provider to make my unit tests single threaded :)

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't even looked using Rx because I can't use it on the application itself (it's not on the approved technology list for production environments at the place I'm working).  But it turns out I could potentially use Rx just for the unit tests, as they'll only be executed on dev boxes and our build server.  Your solution certainly does sound like an elegant one.  Do you have any sample code you can post for the mock IScheduler you used to make your unit tests single threaded?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that's pretty much the conclusion I had come to when looking at this last night.  Hopefully I'll get to use Rx commercially on my next project, and maybe I will make use of your idea then!  I still find it a bit shocking that Microsoft does not appear to have provided a better solution for Silverlight unit testing yet, despite the post-PDC positioning of Silverlight implying a big focus on line-of-business apps.  It seems to have just been all hands on deck on WP7 recently.  Now that WP7 has shipped, perhaps Microsoft will finally address this unit testing issue properly :)

Comment: I'm also very sad about the unit testing story in silverlight. Jetbrains should step in :)

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one - it's difficult to understand why more people aren't shouting about this.  I agree - JetBrains should pick this up, because Microsoft certainly doesn't show any signs of doing so yet!  I suppose there's still a chance that that ScottGu will announce something in this space in his keynote at the Silverlight Firestarter event next week - let's see...

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

I'd already settled on using StatLight for my continuous integration server, but I was looking for a solution to allow me to run asynchronous Silverlight unit tests directly in VS2010 during development.

Inspired by Rob Fonseca-Ensor's suggestion to use Rx (see his separate answer on this page), I took another look at the issue.  That led me to find a non-Rx solution to the problem of using AgUnit to run async Silverlight unit tests.

The solution I think I will use - at least for now - is the combination of:

- Silverlight Unit Test Framework
- ReSharper 5.1
- AgUnit ReSharper plugin
- [Mock async pattern]

My ViewModels have bespoke service classes injected into them which provide abstractions of my (auto-generated) WCF service reference classes.  To help provide access to the WCF service methods, my bespoke service classes also rely on another common class which wraps the async pattern.  For my unit tests, I was already mocking my WCF service reference classes and my bespoke service classes with Moq - but I hadn't looked at mocking my async pattern wrapper class.

So I decided to mock my async pattern wrapper class as well.  The attraction of doing this was that I thought I *might* then be able to use Rx with a mock IScheduler (as Rob suggested in his answer) in all my mocks, while leaving my real classes free of any references to Rx (which is a requirement because for this project at the place I'm working, I need to keep Rx out of any code which gets deployed to a production environment).  However, once I'd mocked the wrapper class, I realised that I didn't even need Rx, and that there was an even simpler solution - which I should have really looked at before.  It's pretty trivial - all I really needed to do was mock the wrapper class and ensure that it called Invoke on the callback operations, rather than calling BeginInvoke.  This ultimately prevents the callbacks which work fine when running under the Silverlight Unit Test Framework in a browser session from going into a black hole when the unit tests are run by AgUnit within VS2010.  (Allowing the callbacks to go into black hole when using AgUnit would of course have prevented the individual tests from completing properly, and could have led to either timeouts or - worse still - false positives in the test results.)

In the absence of better advice from any subsequent answers to this question, this appears to be the easiest way for me to handle this scenario - allowing my async unit tests to run in AgUnit without requiring Rx in my production code.

For anyone else not facing company-imposed restrictions on deploying code that uses Rx (which is still a DevLabs project) to production, I think Rob's solution would definitely be worth looking at.

Comment: do you have any links to refer for a step by step guid for implementing unit testing for silverlight applications. I could n't find any after googling

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the AgUnit plugin.

AgUnit blocks asynchronous unit testing to speed up the test run. Under the covers it uses the same code as the Silverlight Unit Test Framework test runner, but this runner is very slow if you have to handle a large number of tests. I've seen differences between almost half an hour and a few minutes for a couple thousand tests.

That said, if you do want asynchronous testing, it's a very isolated part of AgUnit that does this. I'll try to create a build with it disabled. In the future this will be a configuration option or an attribute, I've not decided yet.

Feel free to contact me with any questions or requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about the recently released [Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff655021%28v=msdn.10%29). Currently it only accessible to MSDN subscribers, and it only works with certain editions of VS2010 (Premium, Ultimate and Test Pro).

Here is a quick overview: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140410135309/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amit_chatterjee/archive/2010/11/16/visual-studio-2010-feature-pack-2-released-new-set-of-testing-capabilities.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  As it happens, I'm using VS2010 Professional, so I believe that rules it out for me.  But yes, I had read about Feature Pack 2.  All the blurb about it tends to refer to UI tests specifically, so I was assuming that it wouldn't have anything to offer for the problem I raised (as I mentioned in my question, I'm an concerned purely with ViewModel tests here, not with View tests).  But I'd be happy to be proven wrong.  Do you have any specific comments on how Feature Pack 2 might help me address my requirement - running async ViewModel unit tests directly in VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a normal unit test project in VS.NET, add my Silverlight assembly in references and write unit test classes.

So everything works out of the box. What's a problem with this solution?

Comment: Yes, I've seen others talking about using this solution too. But aside from the purist point that your tests would be running your Silverlight code against the 'full' .NET CLR rather than the CoreCLR, doesn't this solution limit the references that you can have in your SL code? I'd be happy to be proven wrong - but as I understood it, if you reference a SL assembly from a non-SL project then you're restricted by the 'assembly portability' feature of SL4.  In my case, my ViewModels reference Prism assemblies.  I'd be interested to know which parts of your SL app you're writing tests against.

Comment: You probably use MVVM approach, so what you test in unit tests is ViewModel, which is mostly data access, business rules, INotifyPropertyChanged-objects. The CLR layer (specific to SL or full .NET) used in this case is very thin and well tested by MS itself.

Comment: Yes, I do indeed use MVVM - and I'm *mostly* interested in testing ViewModels (although there are other classes that I test too, including sanity tests against Views). And yes, the CLR used in ViewModels is very thin. But my point was that references used by ViewModels are not necessarily always limited to the 5 CLR assemblies allowed under assembly portability. References to Prism assemblies would be one example. Even without using Prism, you would likely use ICommand from System.Windows.dll. As I said, I'd be interested to know specifically what you've tested successfully with this approach?

Comment: 5 CLR dlls + unlimited number of dlls using these fine (like Prism core dlls). But I must say, we dont use Prism (we use lighter and better version of Caliburn.Micro), so I could be wrong with this assumption

Comment: Unlimited number of dlls using these - yes of course, I appreciate that.  Prism assemblies *do* reference system assemblies beyond simply the 5 allowed under assembly portability though.  They have to, not least because Prism's DelegateCommand implements ICommand. (eg. Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.dll references System.Windows.dll).

Comment: Interestingly, it's not the act of directly or indirectly referencing an assembly beyond the 5 allowed under assembly portability in one's code that causes one's unit tests to fail.  The issue is more what ultimately gets called from those assemblies.  So one could - if one wanted to - test code that uses ICommand or DelegateCommand using a regular (full CLR) unit test project.  Only if one does something silly (eg. calling MessageBox.Show directly from a ViewModel rather than injecting in a messaging service dependecy) would the unit test actually blow up. [TBC after 600 char comment limit]

Comment: [continued] So to be fair, this approach does does allow testing for a lot of scenarios.  But it does depend how widely you want to be able to test.  Although the vast majority of my tests are against ViewModels, I still want to retain the *ability* to test my whole app (eg. integration tests against Views, testing of any custom controls).  Artificially restricting which parts of your SL code you can test because a test framework runs SL code on the full CLR rather than CoreCLR just seems a bit hacky to me.  This one of the reasons why the SL Unit Test Framework was created in the first place.